# How do I see the location path of an application?

Tags: applications, path

I need to check the path to a program -- I want to point to the binary, not to the ".app" which is a directory. How do I do this?

Comment: Almost every .app foder on OSX has it's binary inside Contents/MacOS folder. For example: `/Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail`. To see the .app in Finder simply ⌘+Click it's icon in the Dock.

Comment: Most of the times the binary is named after the app but to double check, just right click on the app, choose **Show Package Contents** and navigate to the path mentioned by Mateusz.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek - put it as Answer :) completely correct

Comment: @megadroid same for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to your `Applications` folder, right click on any app, choose **Show Package Contents** and navigate to `Contents/MacOS/`. Most of the times, the binary is named after the app so, if using the path on a script, you'll be mostly safe by using `/Applications/(appname).app/Contents/MacOS/(appname)`, where `(appname)` is, well, the name of the app. If the app name has a whitespace in it, eg. **Sublime Text**, don't forget to put the path between double quotes (or escape it), in your script.

Comment: Applications don't have to be in /Applications, they can be anywhere

Comment: True but `/Applications` always has applications in it, even if just OS X stock applications. I just provided `Applications` as a base folder example so I could construct the full path to the binary.

Answer (score 1):

As @megadroid posted, Applications have executable in `Contents/MacOS` directory. However executable name not necessarily is the same as app name. To get exact executable name, You can read it from **Info.plist** file (under `CFBundleExecutable` key) or do it from **Terminal.app** with for example:

```
APP_PATH="/Applications/Mail.app"
echo "$APP_PATH"/Contents/MacOS/$(defaults read "$APP_PATH/Contents/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
```

Just change `APP_PATH` variable. Result:
`/Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail`